# CSS Vertical Text within Datagrid

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

**Issue:**

Text correct changes to vertical however within the Gridview the text does not go onto one line and the browser renders based on the horizontal box it is in.

There is alot out there is vertical alignment but not within the gridview itself.

**Aim:**

To get the text sidewards - Done
To get the text sidewards and the boundfield to be the height of the text rather than the width - not done

**Notes:**

Please note this is an ASP gridview not a datagridview

**CSS:**

```
 .Grid th    
 {             
    vertical-align:bottom;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); 
 }
```

**Sample of Grid:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4"
        DataKeyNames="PId" GridLines="None" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True"
        AllowSorting="True" CssClass="Grid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt"   DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" PageSize="20" HeaderStyle="Header"  EmptyDataText="Please search to show results // Nothing found"
        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"> <headerstyle CssClass="Header" />
        <Columns>

<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ColumnA" ReadOnly="True" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true"/>
```

Comment: You have to think in reverse, I just worked on something like this myself, height is now width and width is now height.

Comment: Also something to help you would be to create the issue in a fiddle with the issue shown.